# How to find a specific pattern in some Access data?

Tags: sql, ms-access, pattern-matching

I have ex 17 rows and 2 columns in my tabel. Like this:

```
ColA  ColB
----  ----
X     1   
X     2   
X     3   
X     a   
Y     1   
Y     2   
Y     a   
Z     4   
Z     4   
Z     b   
Q     1   
Q     2   
Q     3   
Q     a   
W     4   
W     b   
W     5
```

Is there a way to look for a pattern in colB of 1,2,3,a for the same value of ColA?
That would give me at output of X and Q.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sample data shows distinct rows.  In that case, you can use this `GROUP BY` query.

```sql
SELECT y.ColA
FROM YourTable AS y
WHERE y.ColB In ('1','2','3','a')
GROUP BY y.ColA
HAVING Count(*) = 4;
```

If your actual data might include duplicate rows, you can start with `SELECT DISTINCT` in a subquery before applying the `GROUP BY`.

```sql
SELECT sub.ColA
FROM
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT y.ColA, y.ColB
        FROM YourTable AS y
        WHERE y.ColB In ('1','2','3','a')
    ) AS sub
GROUP BY sub.ColA
HAVING Count(*) = 4;
```

Comment: Looks like this can be done in many ways. I seems like this is the simplest solution. Thanks for reply's.

Answer (score 1):

*(I've assumed that your table is named [PatternData].)*

If you use Allen Browne's [`ConcatRelated`](http://allenbrowne.com/func-concat.html) function you can create a query to "string together" all of the [ColB] values for each distinct value of [ColA] like this...

```sql
SELECT
    ColA,
    ConcatRelated("ColB", "PatternData", "ColA=""" & ColA & """" , "ColB", "") AS ColB_values
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT ColA FROM PatternData)
```

...returning...

```
ColA  ColB_values
----  -----------
Q     123a       
W     45b        
X     123a       
Y     12a        
Z     44b
```

Then you can use the above query as the basis for a query to find the [ColA] values with the desired pattern

```sql
SELECT ColA
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            ColA,
            ConcatRelated("ColB", "PatternData", "ColA=""" & ColA & """" , "ColB", "") AS ColB_values
        FROM (SELECT DISTINCT ColA FROM PatternData)
    )
WHERE ColB_values = "123a"
```

...returning...

```
ColA
----
Q   
X
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is one possible solution:

```
WITH
  data AS (
    SELECT 'X' cola, '1' colb FROM dual
    UNION ALL SELECT 'X' cola, '2' FROM dual
    UNION ALL SELECT 'X', '3' FROM dual
    UNION ALL SELECT 'X', 'a' FROM dual
    UNION ALL SELECT 'Y', '1' FROM dual
    UNION ALL SELECT 'Y', '2' FROM dual
    UNION ALL SELECT 'Y', 'a' FROM dual
    UNION ALL SELECT 'Z', '4' FROM dual
    UNION ALL SELECT 'Z', '4' FROM dual
    UNION ALL SELECT 'Z', 'b' FROM dual
    UNION ALL SELECT 'Q', '1' FROM dual
    UNION ALL SELECT 'Q', '2' FROM dual
    UNION ALL SELECT 'Q', '3' FROM dual
    UNION ALL SELECT 'Q', 'a' FROM dual
    UNION ALL SELECT 'W', '4' FROM dual
    UNION ALL SELECT 'W', '5' FROM dual
    UNION ALL SELECT 'W', 'b' FROM dual
  ),
  data_agg AS (
    SELECT cola, listagg(colb) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY colb) AS agg_colb
      FROM data
    GROUP BY cola
  )
SELECT cola
  FROM data_agg da
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
                FROM data_agg
              WHERE cola != da.cola
                AND agg_colb = da.agg_colb
             )
;
```

Edit: ops, for some reason I thought you were using Oracle... Hopefully, you'll be able to modify above query to be able to use it.